# starting postgres is failing

Tags: postgresql, macos

I have installed on the postgresql from [EDB](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/postgresql_journey/02_installing/04_macos/)
then, pc restarted however the postgres didn't restart,

**1. I tried to start it with command `postgres` but got the error**

```
postgres: could not access the server configuration file "/Library/PostgreSQL/15/data/postgresql.conf": Permission denied
```

**2. then with sudo**
`sudo postgres`

```
The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for
more information on how to properly start the server.
```

**3. lastly with**

`sudo -u postgres postgres`

```
LOCATION:  find_my_exec, exec.c:149
LOG:  42501: could not identify current directory: Permission denied
LOCATION:  find_my_exec, exec.c:149
FATAL:  XX000: postgres: could not locate my own executable path
LOCATION:  getInstallationPaths, postmaster.c:1548
```

Is there any other way which I can start it?

Comment: Me, I'd ditch that installation and clean it all out, then head to https://postgresapp.com.  A much much much easier way into Postgres on a Mac. No, I'm not the developer, just a well satisfied user.

Comment: Or use one of the cloud companies offering Postgres for a couple pennies per hour.

Comment: This Question may be off-topic for Stack Overflow. Perhaps better posted on sister site DBA.StackExchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use docker to run postgres

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Once the postgres container gets created you can use postgres using docker container id

docker exec -it POSTGRE_DOCKER_ID /bin/bash